# ctl-x-map key map has entries of different kind

Tags: elisp, key-bindings, keymap

when i run,

```
 (dolist (elt ctl-x-map)
             (print elt))
```

it prints,

```
#^[nil nil keymap 
#^^[3 0 pop-global-mark nil list-buffers save-buffers-kill-terminal list-directory eval-last-sexp find-file nil nil indent-rigidly nil kmacro-keymap downcase-region (keymap (108 . set-language-environment) (99 . universal-coding-system-argument) (28 . set-input-method) (88 . set-next-selection-coding-system) (120 . set-selection-coding-system) (112 . set-buffer-process-coding-system) (107 . set-keyboard-coding-system) (116 . set-terminal-coding-system)
#^^[3 0 pop-global-mark nil list-buffers save-buffers-kill-terminal list-directory eval-last-sexp find-file nil nil indent-rigidly nil kmacro-keymap downcase-region (keymap (108 . set-language-environment) (99 . universal-coding-system-argument) (28 . set-input-method) (88 . set-next-selection-coding-system) (120 . set-selection-coding-system) (112 . set-buffer-process-coding-system) (107 . set-keyboard-coding-system) (116 . set-terminal-coding-system) (70 . set-file-name-coding-system) (114 . revert-buffer-with-coding-system) (102 . set-buffer-file-coding-system)) set-goal-column delete-blank-lines mark-page read-onl
(67108896 . pop-global-mark)

(C-left . previous-buffer)

(left . previous-buffer)

(C-right . next-buffer)
```

I expected Ctl-x-map to be a plain map with key sequence as key and function name as value `(ex - (C-left . previous-buffer))`. But the second & third entry that begins with `#^^[` proves it to be wrong. Is ctl-x-map variable, some sort of map within a map ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a full keymap, not a sparse keymap.  That is, it has an entry that is a char-table.

See the Elisp manual, node [`Format of Keymaps`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Format-of-Keymaps.html).

It says this about a char-table entry (emphasis added):

> **char-table**
>
> If an element of a keymap is a char-table, it counts as holding bindings for all character events with no modifier bits (see modifier bits): ***element n is the binding for the character with code n***. This is a compact way to record lots of bindings. A keymap with such a char-table is called a full keymap. Other keymaps are called sparse keymaps.

Comment: a `char-table` is a vector. why does a vector sit inside a key-map? and i see in above example - second entry, many function names like `list-buffers, list-directory,find-file` don't have any key mapping at all?

Comment: Did you read the doc I pointed you to? Yes, a char-table is a vector. It is used for a full keymap.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar the position of those names in the vector indicates the key they are bound to.

Comment: @Malabarba: ...which is another way of saying, as the manual puts it, "*element n is the binding for the character with code n*".

Comment: @Drew Indeed. ;-) Sometimes rephrasing a statement helps people understand it.